# Fastest way to insert data into an Sql Server Database using C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I' d like to know what is the fastest way to insert data into an Sql Server Database.
Currently I' m using SqlCommand with "INSERT" command, but it takes a lot of time, cause I have to insert a lot of rows like 500k.
Could you suggest me what it' s the best solution in my case?
I have also read that I could use SqlBulkCopy, do you think it could be a good solution?

Comment: Try it to do using entity framework and pass data using model https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What does your code look like? How much time is "a lot"?

Comment: possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Comment: What is the role played by MySql in your problem?

Comment: Sorry sirs, I' m new in the forum and I thought that it was the correct tag because it was suugested. Sorry again

Comment: @Xavave it could be if we know that EF is involved here.

Comment: Are you inserting row by row, or do you batch multiple inserts into one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about routine 'programmatic' data imports, [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go in my experience. Otherwise, database admin tricks on the server itself would probably more suitable.

> Microsoft SQL Server includes a popular command-line utility named bcp
>   for quickly bulk copying large files into tables or views in SQL
>   Server databases. The SqlBulkCopy class allows you to write managed
>   code solutions that provide similar functionality. There are other
>   ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements, for
>   example) but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance advantage
>   over them.

One place I worked for we used to import and merge about a million records every day. We used a combination of [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a(v=vs.110).aspx) and stored procedures. A bulk copy would import to a 'scratch' table and stored procedures would do a [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) or [UPDATE SELECT (SO has questions with good examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) to merge the data. Th whole thing used to take under a minute (maybe two).

> With SQL, you can copy information from one table into another. The
>   INSERT INTO SELECT statement copies data from one table and inserts it
>   into an existing table.

I found BulkCopy to be hard to maintain but the performance benefit makes it bearable. Also, if you have a separate table (matching the DataTable) to receive the import, it is easier to manage.

Comment: I tried with SqlBulkCopy and it works very well. I have a question, if I add rows trough SqlBulkCopy, do I have to select data and merge data with the new rows, or WriteToServer() funciton merge data automatically?

Comment: WriteToServer() does not merge data AFAIK. The solution I suggest is that after bulk import you run a data specific INSERT INTO SELECT or UPDATE SELECT WHERE statement, for example only update the rows that have a different value of certain field or timestamp.

Comment: Just edited the answer with a link to an UPDATE SELECT statement. Just remembered that's what we used to use to merge the data.

Answer (score -1):

Use bulk copy it will increase performance significantly

See here for reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use SQLBulkCopy, before that make sure all non clustered index on the table you are inserting record should be dropped then re-create it, it will be much faster for your case.